Why there is no cavitation in water towers?
Water towers seem very high, some are more than 10 meters. With such high water towers, is cavitation possible in the pipe supplying water from large tank to the delivery pipe on the ground? Is the pressure at bottom more than atmospheric?
TLDR: Can cavitation happen in water towers in the long vertical pipe?

pressure at the depth of 10 m is more than atmospheric pressure

What is removing the water from the pipe? Suction of a pump? Or pressure from head? Just remember what causes cavitation.

you seem to think the long pipe makes the pressure at the bottom lower.  Pressure at the bottom is higher just due to the water column.  You could have this problem if you drew water out of a tank from the top (and you would deserve it for making a dumb design choice).

You make sure flow velocities and pipe bend radii are kept below the critical cavitation indicies for the range of operating conditions, fault conditions, etc.

Water exits tank from the bottom and enters tank, via ground pumps, from the top. System is gravity fed.  No pumps on exit so where would cavitation take place?
